# Javascript else condition statement not working with JSON respnse

Tags: jquery

I have the following code. A request is sent to a payment api gateway which checked for a bank account details. On response which returns `status == true or false` I was able to get the **true** part but on **false**, the error was not displaying.

Json returned on false:

```
status  false

message "Could not resolve account name. Check parameters or try again."
```

[image]

**For success response part**

[image]

JQuery part

```js
$.ajax({
    url: url_api,
    type: 'GET',
    data:{
        "account_number" :account_number,
        "bank_code": bank_code
    },
    beforeSend: function(){
        $(".resolve").html('<div class=" alert alert-info">
        Please wait while resolving your account details</div>');
    },
    complete:function(result){
        $(".resolve").hide();

    },
    dataType:"Json",
    success: function(result){
        if(result['status'] == true){
            $(".resolve").hide();
            $('.recipient-name').val(result['data']['account_name']);
            //$('.recipient-number').val(result['data']['account_number']);
        }
        else{
            alert(result['message']);

            $('.resolve').html('<div class="alert alert-danger">     
                <strong>'+result['message']+'</strong></div>');
        }
    }
});
```

The **if stmt** is executing but not the **else stmt**. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: As you get an error, probably you will need to define also the `error` as the `success` function is not executed

Comment: *"Json returned on false..."*: what follows is not JSON.

Comment: Typo in `dataType:'Json` .... the `J` should be lower case. Show us what `response actually looks like. What is shown is just some text

Comment: @charlietfl I have added images for a clarification.